# Browse database tabels in Flutter with Stetho or other program

Tags: android, flutter, stetho

Im trying to migrate from Android to Flutter programming. I want to know if there is any program that could give me access to the database tabels in Flutter?

For Android I used a program called Stetho for browsing my database. I just installed it by adding a dependency to it in build.gradle;

```
 dependencies {
     ....
     implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
     implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'
     .... }
```

then importing it to my main class;

```
 @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
     Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
     new OkHttpClient.Builder().addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor()).build();
```

Can I achieve this in Flutter also?